# replace slide out tags text with static text on tumblr theme

Tags: themes, tumblr

I'm editing this theme  > http://alpha-sleeplessthemes.tumblr.com/ (code found here http://pastebin.com/qKLDN0xd)

The theme has posts' tags hidden under a # and they slide out, If you scroll to the ' Testing Ask Box ' post you will see what I am talking about.

I want to change this to static text that wraps within the width of the box underneath where it says " Posted: 1 year ago - With: 0 notes - Reblog " but I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rule `#tags:hover` entirely.

Remove the following properties from the `#tags` rule:

```
position: absolute; 
margin-top: -15px;
margin-left: 390px;
```

Now it will be always visible and you can position it the way you want it.

---

To figure this out, I right clicked on "#", selected "Inspect element" and then tried to understand what pushed that element (`div#tag`) to the side. In this case it was those three properties.